# Can't edit my comment or answer

Tags: support, ios-app

Can I edit my answer or comment? I don't see an obvious link or button.

With my iPad, autocorrect sometimes does weird things, or I literally fat finger words. Most of my typing is with two thumbs. I just posted an answer where the word 'the' should be 'then'. It would be nice to quickly edit the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find a menu of options (including editing) by tapping on the three dots at the bottom right of a question, answer, or comment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I did not see those dots at all.  Given all the whitespace, I would like to see a bigger icon

Comment: I agree, they could definitely be more prominent. I'll make sure to jot this down and find a better UX for it.